# Reuse texinfo in doxygen

Tags: documentation, markdown, doxygen, texinfo

Are there any tools for converting texinfo files into something Doxygen can process (presumably markdown)? I have a bunch of old texinfo files that I'd like to link in with the doxygen docs we have. I guess I'll generate html from the texinfo and link to that from doxygen source files if I have to, but I'd rather integrate the texinfo docs into the doxygen ones.

Comment: A good question and one you'd have thought there was an answer to, but I can't find anything either.  "Pandoc" seems to be the stock answer for this sort of thing, but I don't think that helps either in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this on and off for legacy documentation on my project.  I've found a solution that, while not completely automated, is workable.  Since Doxygen can process `markdown` files, I've been converting my texi files into mardown.

1. Convert the texi file to html via `texi2html`

   $ texi2html foo.texi
2. Convert the html file to markdown via `pandoc`

   $ pandoc -f html -t markdown -o foo.md foo.html
3. Clean up the resulting markdown file with your markdown editor of choice.  There are a plethora of them, but on OSX I use `Markdown Pro`.
4. Edit your `Doxyfile` and tell Doxygen to process the markdown files in the directory.  Either add the file to your `INPUT` list,  or add the `.md` extension to the `FILE_PATTERNS` tag.  More information about `Doxygen`'s markdown support may be found here:

   - http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html